# Как в некорректном массиве объектов получить максимальное значение?

Tags: javascript

Ошибка из за того что одно значение с пустым объектом, пробовал проверку добавлять, но все равно не срабатывает

Как в reduce пропустить такое значение?

```js
let obj = [
  {},
  { season: 2 },
  { season: 9 },
  { season: 5 },
];
let type = 'season';

let max = Object.values(obj).reduce((p, c) => (p[type] < c[type]) ? c : p)[type];
console.log(max);

let max2 = Object.values(obj).reduce((p, c) => c[type] !== undefined ? ((p[type] < c[type]) ? c : p) : 0)[type];
console.log(max2);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Как в некорректном массиве объектов получить максимальное значение?

Предложу такой вариант нахождения максимального элемента в массиве...

```js
let a = [
  {},
  { season: 2 },
  { season: 9 },
  { season: 5 },
];

const max = Math.max(...a.map(o => o.season ?? -Infinity))
console.log(max)
```

Еще вариант...

```js
let a = [
  {},
  { season: 2 },
  { season: 9 },
  { season: 5 },
];

const max = a.reduce((m, o) => Math.max(m, o.season ?? -Infinity), -Infinity)
console.log(max)
```

Comment: Двойной проход для нахождения максимума - для меня крайне излишне :)

Comment: @EzioMercer, добавил еще вариант, с одним проходом...

Comment: 2-ой вариант я не сразу его заметил, но он самый лучший вариант по производительности из всего что тут в ответах есть

Comment: @DaniilLoban С чего вы это взяли? https://jsbench.me/8tlgmkki3p/1

Comment: @EzioMercer с тестов разумеется, Ваш вариант на 1ms медлеенее (тестил на ноде, 1000000 операции) 38.423ms и  37.258ms

Comment: @DaniilLoban Значит зависит от машины и всяких другх параметров запуска :)

Comment: @EzioMercer да, разумеется, у меня тем более не шустрая.

Answer (score 2):

Попытаюсь объяснить где именно Вы ошиблись, в обоих случаях ошибка в том что Вы не указываете начальное значение для `reduce`, но во втором случае еще чуть более сложный вариант — в тернарнике где подставляете `0` в качестве ответа, должен быть объект со свойством равным 0. Наличие свойств лучше проверять через `hasOwnProperty` и да начальный минимум лучше брать за `-Infinity` как указано в ответе **@ksa**

```
let max3 = Object.values(obj)
  .reduce((p, c) => (p[type] < c[type]) ? c : p,
  {[type]: 0} // этого не было указано
)[type];
console.log(max3);

let max4 = Object.values(obj).reduce((p, c) =>  
  c.hasOwnProperty(type) 
    ? (p[type] < c[type] ? c : p)
    : {[type]:0}, // вместо 0
  {[type]: 0})[type] // не было указано 
console.log(max4);
```

Answer (score 2):

Замечания:

1. Я не очень понял зачем вам вообще `Object.values`, в вашем случае, можно к массиву сразу применять `reduce`
2. Вы не указади начальное значение для `reduce`, а потому он взял как начальное значение первый элемент - пустой объект
3. Наличие свойтсва отедельно проверять не вижу смысла, можно просто воспользоваться [оператором нулевого слияния (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) и если нет, то подставить минус бесконечность

```js
const objects = [
  {},
  { season: 2 },
  { season: 9 },
  {},
  { season: 5 },
];

const max = objects.reduce((max, object) => {
  const value = object.season ?? -Infinity;
  
  return value > max ? value : max;
  
}, -Infinity);

console.log(max);
```